# Short form of name Adriano

Tags: name, proper-nouns

I am wondering if there is a short form(s) of Italian name Adriano?

Googled but could not find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My uncle was called Adriano and as far as I know no short forms were ever used, but remeber that these kind of things vary very much regionally (in the north-east the short of Giuseppe is *Bepi* and of Francesco is *Checco* or *Cesco*, in other parts of Italy the corresponding forms are *Giusè* and *Francè*)

Comment: Penso che "Adri" sia un nomignolo che si sente in giro.

Comment: @DenisNardin: ...or Peppe or Beppe (for Giuseppe, as in “Peppe er tosto” for Giuseppe Gioacchino Belli) and even Ciccio (for Francesco).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only abbreviation I'm aware of is "Adri", like [user519 states](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/short-form-of-name-adriano/6919#comment13772_6840). It can be used for the less frequent female name "Adriana" as well.

Note that, like many Italian name abbreviations ending with the "i" sound, it can both be written locally ending with an "i", or with an "y" to give it an international tone. Apart of being some sort of Anglicism, I'm positive many people see abbreviations ending with a "y" more suited for female names.

In your case, also if no official rule is defined (I'm only giving my view on what's more informally used based on my experience), you could abbreviate Adriano in "Adri" and Adriana in "Adry", although the sound is the same.

Also note that near Rome and central Italy (Lazio region), but in the south as well (Campania and in particular Naples come to mind), almost every name that has an "a" (even if it sounds strange in case the "a" is in the first syllable) is abbreviated by putting an accent on it and cutting the name there.
So, Adriano becomes "Adrià", Pasquale is shortened to "Pasquà" and Giovanni to "Giovà".
Please note that, apart of being a rather regionalized use, such abbreviations are more common when speaking directly to the interested person (more commonly, when calling out loud to catch his/her attention, maybe when seeing him by chance and greeting him).

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Thanks! I hope to contribute in getting this site out of beta :)

Comment: “such abbreviations is more common when speaking directly...”: indeed. I'd even say that they are used exclusively like this, as a kind of vocative case. And it doesn't happen just not with an “a”, but potentially truncating almost any name after the stressed syllable (“France'”, as already mentioned, “Danie'”, “Anto'” and so on).

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake by considering this only with the letter "a", I didn't think about it but it happens equally with any other vowel.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski: nothing compared to the word jumble that is my «it doesn't happen just not with an “a”», Dude.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't even notice it with a quick read. The sense was clear and that's the important thing :)

Comment: Perfect answer. Personally, I'd say that *Adrià* sounds slightly weird not because it starts with an A, but because the *ia* sound is weird: *dria* is a long and awkward syllable to pronounce in a single unit, so that i is not 100% "diphthongized".

Comment: Indeed. Typical Rome's "burino" :) 100% funny but surely not formal. But I think I got misunderstood on the first syllable thing. I did not mean Adrià sounds weird since it as an "a" in its first syllable (as the "a" which gets the accent is in the third one), I mean that if you were to abbreviate "Mara" with "Mà" that won't do, as you end up with a "word" way too short and ambiguous (it can sound like the conjunction or like you could quickly and confidentially address your own mother).

Comment: It should be added that yes, people in the south tend to abbreviate whatever name they can... However people in the north often find it to be inappropriate and impolite. So beware.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@user519 on "Adri"](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/short-form-of-name-adriano/6919#comment13772_6840) and I would like to add something about its pronunciation.
Due to the effort in articulating the cluster /d/ + /r/, the voiced alveolar fricative may sound doubled and the /a/ shorter (/addri/). Just to make myself understood, this also happens in some regional dialects with the word "libro" which becomes /libbro/.

Comment: For personal curiosity: your name seems to indicate an origin from my area (around Venice and Treviso) but the description of your pronunciation sounds roughly "southern". What regional dialects are you referring to?

Comment: Well, actually my origins are from your area, but I've never lived there. I'm referring to a dialect spoken in a couple of villages situated in the High Appenines between the provinces of Modena and Reggio Emilia. A similar regional variety is also found in some valleys of Lombardia, but - I must admit - I don't remember exactly where. :)